# Laravel + Vue App with plesk not loading all assets

Tags: laravel, vue.js, plesk, laravel-mix

I'm trying to deploy a new version of an app with Plesk but I'm having an issue with the web, the app seems to compile to production just fine, the mixins seems to be fine, it works in localhost just fine (started with the `npm start` command), but when i deploy it in plesk, i can see in the sources inspector in the navigator that not all files are loaded, and the web doesn't completely show or shows a blank screen as a result:

It only shows the footer of the web, the console (both the navigator and laravel's) aren't showing any errors, but in the 'Header' folder in the sources (and in the rest of the folders too) there should be more files that, for some reason, are missing. the error is fixed if i reload the web clearing the caché (ctrl + F5), but i can't expect that every user that stumbles into this problem does that.

The mix-manifest in the public folder seems fine, in fact the app.js file for example gets correctly updated if i modify the id, but the other files are still missing.

public/mix-manifest.json:

```
{
    "/js/app.js": "/js/app.js?id=9ed9d9ef906922ba2f74",
    "/js/manifest.js": "/js/manifest.js?id=f73a8e6469ce0bfff6ad",
    "/js/Header/Header.js": "/js/Header/Header.js?id=572289a95a57bef992cc",
    "/js/Header/Head.js": "/js/Header/Head.js?id=6f6e63843409cf10a96b",
    "/js/Header/SubHeader.js": "/js/Header/SubHeader.js?id=2c0f16a8446c41e8484f",
    "/js/Layout/Footer.js": "/js/Layout/Footer.js?id=e15bf24700aba1f615e0",
    "/js/Layout/Popup.js": "/js/Layout/Popup.js?id=b77aa0d2d06e5c8a58d6",
    "/js/Layout/Contact.js": "/js/Layout/Contact.js?id=31caefe1e319f0d23553",
    "/js/Layout/Login.js": "/js/Layout/Login.js?id=95cc7a34bcef17a6aad3",
    "/js/Layout/Forgot.js": "/js/Layout/Forgot.js?id=d29a97cb144fdcead25b",
    "/js/Layout/Signup.js": "/js/Layout/Signup.js?id=71199f3676ea6b574600",
    "/js/Layout/BottomFooter.js": "/js/Layout/BottomFooter.js?id=50248166ddffadcd33ab",
    "/js/Layout/CookiesPolicy.js": "/js/Layout/CookiesPolicy.js?id=6cc2b16b2b43c8e5e5e0",
    "/js/Layout/Display.js": "/js/Layout/Display.js?id=6fed6a4340fe7cac7e14",
    "/js/Layout/Tooltip.js": "/js/Layout/Tooltip.js?id=a9a00f105f20534af220",
    "/js/LoginForm/Login.js": "/js/LoginForm/Login.js?id=85c0059fd6583bb81531",
    "/js/LoginForm/Forgot.js": "/js/LoginForm/Forgot.js?id=23ada26f31abfb620a97",
    "/js/LoginForm/Signup.js": "/js/LoginForm/Signup.js?id=4d5df3b59165a738835a",
    "/js/Layout/FadePrimary.js": "/js/Layout/FadePrimary.js?id=a5a23bc776784c5965b8",
    "/js/Pickers/InputMenu.js": "/js/Pickers/InputMenu.js?id=c27e17aeab865e24d6f7",
    "/js/Pickers/DatePicker.js": "/js/Pickers/DatePicker.js?id=a06e0674b8fb95ab29d1",
    "/js/Pickers/RangePicker.js": "/js/Pickers/RangePicker.js?id=f1ad6d631d3a9a052679",
    "/js/Pickers/HoursPicker.js": "/js/Pickers/HoursPicker.js?id=ec0562b970eb6ac58b0c",
    "/js/Pickers/BookingDatesPicker.js": "/js/Pickers/BookingDatesPicker.js?id=6d15dc93cb761f4b21a6",
    "/js/Layout/Snackbar.js": "/js/Layout/Snackbar.js?id=a490cd677dc94d1cd748",
    "/js/Layout/Snackbars.js": "/js/Layout/Snackbars.js?id=28553a55a7cd6cc960f7",
    "/js/Layout/ErrorMessage.js": "/js/Layout/ErrorMessage.js?id=f1582f845a6a276b88bf",
    "/js/Header/Selector.js": "/js/Header/Selector.js?id=8ff132c2dc793172f2e7",
    "/js/Header/BreadCrumb.js": "/js/Header/BreadCrumb.js?id=978cae6408bdb90b0709",
    "/js/Header/InputDiscount.js": "/js/Header/InputDiscount.js?id=0406d8c0d35c6effac55",
    "/js/Layout/PopUpChange.js": "/js/Layout/PopUpChange.js?id=d9c71f1eb3b5e2ce12b0",
    "/js/Header/OcupationSelector.js": "/js/Header/OcupationSelector.js?id=6dadaf648da43bbb0b98",
    "/js/Cart/Cart.js": "/js/Cart/Cart.js?id=a00988e65bcac2af6188",
    "/js/FormBooking/FormBooking.js": "/js/FormBooking/FormBooking.js?id=c3d1be2610e19613b41d",
    "/js/Cart/CartSummary.js": "/js/Cart/CartSummary.js?id=2ac29c8b8deda5e68624",
    "/js/FormBooking/Older18.js": "/js/FormBooking/Older18.js?id=03945e3e938bcacb24a3",
    "/js/Spaces/Pax.js": "/js/Spaces/Pax.js?id=808409c2b6a563b56bf9",
    "/js/Spaces/Service.js": "/js/Spaces/Service.js?id=80d20ffbfac229e21b8f",
    "/js/PromotionPackages/PromotionPackageCard.js": "/js/PromotionPackages/PromotionPackageCard.js?id=e3d8a74b5e00243beca0",
    "/js/Spaces/Spaces.js": "/js/Spaces/Spaces.js?id=28b0174fc2ead027bc6b",
    "/js/SpacesList/SpacesList.js": "/js/SpacesList/SpacesList.js?id=1a48a755e0bd5a339870",
    "/js/SpacesList/Info.js": "/js/SpacesList/Info.js?id=f64704f255e49c802004",
    "/js/Extras/Extras.js": "/js/Extras/Extras.js?id=a00cf911a0a7cd323a8c",
    "/js/SpacesList/Comparator.js": "/js/SpacesList/Comparator.js?id=551e5c7129b8384ec339",
    "/js/PromotionPackages/PromotionPackage.js": "/js/PromotionPackages/PromotionPackage.js?id=fa43397345cc279a859c",
    "/js/PromotionPackages/Promotion.js": "/js/PromotionPackages/Promotion.js?id=22841760de257435f333",
    "/js/Layout/PopUpPackage.js": "/js/Layout/PopUpPackage.js?id=da9d939c1f4e9f8f3701",
    "/js/Zones/Zones.js": "/js/Zones/Zones.js?id=6fec71ee55fbeef302d0",
    "/js/UpdateBooking/MyBooking.js": "/js/UpdateBooking/MyBooking.js?id=3d2eb2b26f80ed62f55e",
    "/js/UpdateBooking/MyBookingGroup.js": "/js/UpdateBooking/MyBookingGroup.js?id=a41fe9ee0eea6aced9e2",
    "/js/UpdateBooking/OnlyDates.js": "/js/UpdateBooking/OnlyDates.js?id=3406b36f44f602fadef5",
    "/js/Dashboard/DashboardContainer.js": "/js/Dashboard/DashboardContainer.js?id=755f1bcd412c6b47496d",
    "/js/Dashboard/components/Header.js": "/js/Dashboard/components/Header.js?id=97ddee183bb37056418a",
    "/js/Dashboard/components/RegisterForm.js": "/js/Dashboard/components/RegisterForm.js?id=4062ee3cf9f9906f3d9e",
    "/js/Dashboard/components/RecoveryPass.js": "/js/Dashboard/components/RecoveryPass.js?id=2dff6a18ca10afe1e244",
    "/js/Register/Components.js": "/js/Register/Components.js?id=0d7b892df39e534be2f9",
    "/js/Loyalty/LoyaltyLogin.js": "/js/Loyalty/LoyaltyLogin.js?id=d8e9144ea72ccb611fd5",
    "/js/Loyalty/LoyaltySignUp.js": "/js/Loyalty/LoyaltySignUp.js?id=1a9c2bc35c767b594e01",
    "/js/FormBooking/FormTicketPoints.js": "/js/FormBooking/FormTicketPoints.js?id=fcfeb933b8c0fee71763",
    "/js/Dashboard/components/loyaltySelector.js": "/js/Dashboard/components/loyaltySelector.js?id=9e0efc7c4beeb278e4ed",
    "/js/libs.css": "/js/libs.css?id=013d4d2934e3c1847cd7",
    "/js/libs.js": "/js/libs.js?id=8b416f1a6985a5afcf34",
    "/js/vendor.js": "/js/vendor.js?id=4fcbead4b5f96d39f450"
}
```

I'm kind of out of ideas at this point ¿What could the problem be?¿code?¿plesk configuration?¿leprechauns?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: @GaryHoubre ,I'm sorry, i tried to post some explanatory images, including one of the sources tab of the inspector, but apparently i need lvl 10 for that. I edited the post and added the code in the mix-manifest, maybe that might help, i suspect that the error might be something mixing related, but I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem was the WebpackChunkName of the different components, removing the `/* webpackChunkName: "my-chunk-name" */` of the Vue.components in my app.js the problem was solved. Now the builder create the public files with an ID instead of a proper name, but it actually works.